# How shall I change the setup or the glsl files themselves to connect my shaders to the geometry I'm trying to create in my main.js file?

Tags: javascript, import, three.js, html5-canvas

Here is the setup in my main.js file

```
//.................SETUP................//
import {
  WebGLRenderer,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  Scene,
  BoxGeometry,
  MeshBasicMaterial,
  Mesh,
  Group,
  PlaneGeometry,
  AxesHelper,
  GridHelper,
  DoubleSide,
  DirectionalLight,
  AmbientLight,
  MeshStandardMaterial,
  DirectionalLightHelper,
  Fog,
  TextureLoader,
  CubeTextureLoader,
  SphereGeometry,
  CameraHelper,
  Color,
  ShaderMaterial,
  SphereBufferGeometry,
} from './three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './q.js';
import vertex from './vertex.glsl'
import fragment from './fragment.glsl'
```

And here is the object I intend to creat with the shaders

```
//object
var geometryShader = new SphereBufferGeometry(1, 50, 50)
var materialShader = new ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: vertex,
  fragmentShader: fragment,
})
var meshShader = new Mesh(geometryShader, materialShader);
scene.add(meshShader);
```

And here are the vertex.glsl content I have added to the glsl file so far

```
void main() {
    vec4 localPosition = vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 worldPosition = vec4(modelMatrix * localPosition);
    vec4 viewPosition = vec4(viewMatrix * worldPosition);
    vec4 clipPosition = vec4(projectionMatrix * viewPosition);
    gl_Position = clipPosition;
}
```

Right now the console responds that it expects a type: java script module, but if I change the name of the files from .glsl .js I will get problems since they are written in glsl.

Comment: The vertex and fragment shaders are expected to be a string. When you import it from './vertex.glsl', your bundler thinks you’re trying to import a JS file. You should look up an importer that works with your compiler, or just build it as a string like: `const vertex = “void main(){…}”`

Comment: I tried to change it to a string but received this error message instead: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.